# How to use Wordpress shortcode inside form field value?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm attempting to get a shortcode working inside a form field's value="[shortcode]".

This shortcode grabs a URL parameter and prints it.  This works everywhere else on the page.  It even work in double quotes outside of my form.  It also works inside the form as the Submit button text.  For some reason, it just won't work within the value="".

This is for an ActiveCampaign form.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried assigning the shortcode value to a variable and then assign the variable to the form field - or maybe skip the quotes if you're getting `[shortcode]` in the form field?

Comment: I'm placing all of this code within the HTML module of Beaver Builder plugin.  Unfortunately, that doesn't allow PHP.

Comment: Shortcodes only work when they're placed in the content editor.

Comment: This shortcode is working within this HTML module outside of the value="".  When I just add it below the form, or even as the text for the Submit button, it works perfectly.  Is there something different about these other areas?  Beaver Builder states that shortcodes do work within their HTML module, which I've seen is true.

Comment: In addition, I did try creating a page without using Beaver Builder and saw the same behavior. The shortcode works on the page, even within the submit button text.  Just not when placed within the quote: value="".

Comment: I've no idea what Beaver Builder is so I don't know if this is possible, but to execute a shortcode outside the content editor you need to use the WP `do_shortcode` function. e.g. if you were creating your form in a PHP file, you'd do something like `value="<?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the information about using a shortcode outside the content editor. That's useful. The standard Beaver Builder HTML module doesn't accept PHP. I found a plugin called PHP Everywhere that adds the ability to accept PHP anywhere within Wordpress. Using this, I was able to use PHP within the HTML module to use the _GET variable to grab the parameter. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Hire one solution. Using dynamic population in Gravity Forms allows you to dynamically populate a field with a value (or values depending on the field type). This value can be passed via Query Strings, Shortcode and/or Hooks. This walk-through will give you an example of how to use each method of dynamic population to dynamically populate a field on your form! https://docs.gravityforms.com/using-dynamic-population/