# ACF - Display Multiple Repeater Images

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode

My end goal is to create a gallery of Images that when clicked link to an external website. This needs to be done through Advanced Custom Fields, so I made a repeater that has the image and link in the same row:

```
link1 | cover_image1 
link2 | cover_image2
```

Right now I'm inserting this code into a text editor inside my webpage. I also imported some short-code from [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-shortcode/), that allows me to use %ROW% as an iterator.

"attachments" is the parent repeater and "link" and "cover_image" are the children.

```
[acf_repeater field="attachments"]

external url = [acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_link']
image url = [acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image'] 

<a href =[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_link'] >
<img src = [acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image'] width="300" height="214" />
</a>

[/acf_repeater]
```

The webpage renders this:[image]

Where the broken image contains this code:

```
<img src="[acf" field="attachments_0_cover_image" &#093;="" width="300" height="214">
```

I think [acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image'] in `<img>` isn't resolving all the way to the url, as external url = and image url = both render the correct urls.

Wordpress also converts my code to this after saving, so its probably a syntax error?

```
[acf_repeater field="attachments"]

external url = [acf field = attachments_%ROW%_link]
image url = [acf field = attachments_%ROW%_cover_image]

<a href="[acf">
<img src="[acf" width="300" height="214" />
</a>

[/acf_repeater]
```

I'm not sure how to properly convert [acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image'] to a url in the `<img>` and I could use some help on the proper syntax. Thank you so much for you help!

html for the  attribute per Arian:

```
<div class="fl-module fl-module-rich-text fl-node-5d4926759d7aa" 

data-node="5d4926759d7aa">
    <div class="fl-module-content fl-node-content">
        <div class="fl-rich-text">
    <p>Agenda: <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&amp;resize=640:*">https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&amp;resize=640:*</a></p>
<p>Video Links: <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/cute-cat-photos-1593441022.jpg?crop=0.669xw:1.00xh;0.166xw,0&amp;resize=640:*"></a></p>
<p>Thumbnails: <a href=""></a></p>
<p></p>
<p>external url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHKfrz65KSU<br>
image url = http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/Thumbnail_1.png</p>
<p><a href="[acf" field="attachments_0_link" &#093;=""><br>
<img src="[acf" field="attachments_0_cover_image" &#093;="" width="300" height="214"><br>
</a></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>external url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2lIovmNsUY<br>
image url = http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/Thumbnail_2-1.png</p>
<p><a href="[acf" field="attachments_1_link" &#093;=""><br>
<img src="[acf" field="attachments_1_cover_image" &#093;="" width="300" height="214"><br>
</a></p>
<p><br></p>
<p>external url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDJkFLnmFHU<br>
image url = http://wordpress.local/wp-content/uploads/Thumbnail_3-1.png</p>
<p><a href="[acf" field="attachments_2_link" &#093;=""><br>
<img src="[acf" field="attachments_2_cover_image" &#093;="" width="300" height="214"><br>
</a></p>
<p><br></p>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the broken url all the <img> tag how it has been rendered ?

Comment: Just added some more html from the website, Let me know if you want more! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you try adding `[acf field = attachments_%ROW%_cover_image]` to a string then add it to img tag `<img src="'.$img.'">` like this.

Comment: Could you explain how to add [acf field = attachments_%ROW%_cover_image] to a string?
doing $img = [acf field = attachments_%ROW%_cover_image] isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Not a wordpress guy, but seems like wordpress prevents expanding/executing shortcodes with parameters within html attributes, maybe this could work as workaround if you can put php code there:

```
<?php
$link = do_shortcode("[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_link']");
$cover_img = do_shortcode("[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image']");
?>

<a href="<?= $link ?>">
<img src="<?= $cover_img ?>" width="300" height="214" />
</a>
```

Actually i found comment on this:

> It appears it's using the same quotes for the HTML attribute and the shortcode's attributes that create problems.

at [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241634/how-do-i-use-shortcodes-inside-of-html-tags)

so this may work too:

```
<a href="[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_link']">
<img src="[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image']" width="300" height="214" />
</a>
```

or without shortcode quotes:

```
<a href="[acf field=attachments_%ROW%_link]">
<img src="[acf field=attachments_%ROW%_cover_image]" width="300" height="214" />
</a>
```

last option i can think of is creating parameter-less shortcodes like this:

```
function acflink_shortcode() {
    return do_shortcode("[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_link']");
}
add_shortcode('acflink', 'acflink_shortcode');

function acfimage_shortcode() {
    return do_shortcode("[acf field ='attachments_%ROW%_cover_image']");
}
add_shortcode('acfimage', 'acfimage_shortcode');
```

then using in editor like:

```
<a href="[acflink]">
<img src="[acfimage]" width="300" height="214" />
</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately php isn't allowed in the text box. I think its exclusively html and work-press short codes.

Comment: Doing the second thing resulted in a broken image, although inspecting it resulted in:
```<img loading="lazy" src="" width="300" height="214">```

Comment: Doing the without shortcode quotes results in the same:
```<img loading="lazy" src="" width="300" height="214">```

Comment: @Watson221 found another relevant comment: "There is 2 html element in elementor, after switching to “Custom HTML” element, it’s now working."

Comment: The site uses Beaver Builder, not elementor. There is a specific html element, but that also doesn't render the image

Comment: @Watson221 then thats the real issue here, googled a guy which had same problem with Beaver Builder, he solved it by using plugin PHP Everywhere

Comment: Can you provide a link to his issue please?

Comment: not much info there but here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46508349/how-to-use-wordpress-shortcode-inside-form-field-value